# Is SED able to split this prefix=a,b,c,d into that prefix=a \n prefix=b \n prefix=c

Tags: awk, sed

There is a log file with the following data in it:

`2019-07-18 12:00:00,000 login1 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh,bcd-efg-hij`

I am trying to process that file using sed (or any other bash text processing tool) to get the following output:

`2019-07-18 12:00:00,000 login1 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bcd-efg-hij`

Or the other way around:

- I need to capture part of a line (from its beginning till login info)
- I need to split the remaining part of that line on "," which is separating IDs
- Each new line needs to contain the captured part (date time login) + ID

Comment: Can there be more than two parts at the end, for instance `abc-def-geh,bcd-efg-hij,xyz-...`?

Comment: Yes, there can be up to several hundred of such parts (IDs)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$NF~/,/{split($NF,a,",");$NF="";for(x in a)print $0a[x];next}7' file
```

This line should help.

---

> Yes, there can be up to several hundred of such parts (IDs)

- It is gonna work too.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is more generous tool for your goal. Try this one:

```
perl -nle 'm/(.*) (\S+) (\S+)$/; print "$1 $2 $_" foreach split ",", $3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ': c; s/^\([^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ [^ ]\+\) \([^\n,]\+\),\(.*\)/\1 \3\n\1 \2/; t c; s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/'
```

- `: c` declare label `c` (a short mnemonic from "continue")
- `^\([^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ [^ ]\+\)` - match the first three parts
- `\([^\n,]\+\)` - match the first part up until the comma. Also stop matching when a newline is found, which will be important later...
- `,` - if we stopped at newline, we should stop processing. If we stopped at comma, we should match a comma.
- `\(.*\)` - remember the rest after the comma.
- `\1 \3\n\1 \2` - add the matched part on the end of the input. So that on the next iteration we can match again (and again and again...). We stop matchine then `\3` doesn't has any comma in it anymore, then the `\([^\n,]\+\),` regex part will fail, cause there will be no comma.
- `t c` - if last `s///` command was successful, branch to label `c`. The `s///` will be successful until commas are in string.
- `s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/` - move the first line to be the last. Without it, the last pattern will be the first. Simply match the first line and move it.

Tested with (randomly typed to get some more input data):

```
cat <<EOF |
2019-07-18 12:00:00,000 login1 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh,bcd-efg-hij
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh,bcd-efg-hij,bfdsabfasdh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh,bcd-efg-hij,bfdsabfasdh,fdsmfasfda,f,da,dfas,fd,asf,das,fsd,af,a,fdsafasdfsda,fasd
EOF
sed ': c; s/^\([^ ]\+ [^ ]\+ [^ ]\+\) \([^\n,]\+\),\(.*\)/\1 \3\n\1 \2/; t c; s/\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/'
```

will output:

```
2019-07-18 12:00:00,000 login1 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bcd-efg-hij
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bcd-efg-hij
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bfdsabfasdh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bcd-efg-hij
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bfdsabfasdh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 fdsmfasfda
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 f
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 da
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 dfas
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 fd
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 asf
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 das
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 fsd
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 af
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 a
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 fdsafasdfsda
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 fasd
```

Note that using `\n` inside sed in substitute replacement list is a gnu extension.

Comment: Thank you very much Kami for such a detailed answer/explanation. This indeed does what I wanted to achieve! It looks however, that the tool I sugested is not the best for such a job. pearl or awk based solutions mentioned below are way more performant (when processing files with 500k+ lines)

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes …

`sed` can do this kind of processing. Using `(…)` you can create groups in your search pattern which can be accessed in the replacement using `\N` where `N` is the number of the group.

If there can be at most two IDs then the `sed` command is simple:

```
sed -E 's/(.*,.* )(.*),(.*)/\1\2\n\1\3/'
```

#### … but

if there can be arbitrary many IDs at the end then you would have to fiddle with `sed`'s hold space as you would have to replace a part you just replaced. At that point it makes more sense to switch to another tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$NF~/,/{n=split($NF,p,/,/); sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,""); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $0 p[i]; next} 1' file
2019-07-18 12:00:00,000 login1 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 abc-def-geh
2019-07-18 12:00:00,001 login2 bcd-efg-hij
```

The differences between this and [@Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57092079/1745001) are:

1. It won't cause awk to recompile $0 for the lines that are processed (so it won't change the white space between fields).
2. It will cause awk to resplit $0 into fields for those lines.
3. It will output the parts of the last field in the same order as they
   occurred in the input instead of in "random" (probably hash) order.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(((\S+\s){3})[^,]*),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace the comma following the first three fields by a newline and the first three fields, print, delete and repeat.